# Issue with returning values from an object array

Tags: javascript, sorting

I'm pretty new (a few weeks in) to js and have a question about an incremental game I'm developing. My issue has to do with creating an array from an object I have and then fetching a property of the object, which is used in a compare statement and updated in my HTML.

I have the following object called UPGRADES:

```
var UPGRADES = {

newClothes: {
    name: "New Clothes",
    desc: "Give your bums a new look and some more motivation! \n Bum 
    production bonus: 100%",
    moneyCost: 1000,
    scienceCost: 10,
    requiredScience: 10,
    buildingAffected: BUILDINGS.bumBuilding,
    upgVal: 2,
    id: 'newClothes'
},   
//{upgrade 2}
//{upgrade 3 etc.}        
}
```

For one part of my code I need to go through each element of UPGRADES, return the nth object WITHIN "upgrades" (with newClothes as index 0), and then call (Nth index.scienceCost).

So far I've done the following:

```
var numBuildings = objectLength(BUILDINGS);
var numUpgrades = objectLength(UPGRADES);

function checkVisiblityOnUpgrades () {

var upgArray = [];
for (var a = 0; a < numUpgrades; a++) {
    upgArray[a] = Object.keys(UPGRADES)[a].toString();      
    console.log(UPGRADES.upgArray[a]);

    if (UPGRADES.upgArray[a].requiredScience <= resources.science) {
        var idString = upgArray[a].id.toString();
        getId(idString.concat("Button")).style.visibility = "visible";
        getId(idString.concat("MoneyCostDisp")).innerHTML = 
       numFormat(upgArray[a].moneyCost);
        getId(idString.concat("ScienceCostDisp")).innerHTML = 
        numFormat(upgArray[a].scienceCost);
        }
    }
}
```

I get this error along with it:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
at checkVisiblityOnUpgrades (game.js:268)
at update (game.js:290)
268 is console.log(UPGRADES.upgArray[a]);
```

I was wondering how I would actually go about grabbing the values of the object I wanted. I'm creating an array in `checkVisibilityOnUpgrades()` so I can iterate through each upgrade with a for loop.

Another question I have is: If I was going to store 100+ instances of upgrades, would it be better to switch `UPGRADES` to an array rather than its own object? That way I could grab values a lot more easily.

Comment: which line is game.js:268?

Comment: Your idea will be a problem because you can’t guarantee that the nth item of an object will be consistent. Objects don’t have ordered elements.

Comment: js:268 is `console.log(UPGRADES.upgArray[a]);`

Answer (score 0):

You can drastically simplify your initial logic there with Object.entries:

```
Object.entries(UPGRADES).forEach(({ key, thisUpgradeObject }) => {
  // `key` references the outer property, eg., 'newClothes'
  // `thisUpgradeObject` references the inner object
});
```

So

```
Object.entries(upgArray).forEach(({ key, obj }) => {
  const {
    requiredScience,
    id,
    moneyCost,
    scienceCost,
  } = obj;
  if (requiredScience < resources.science) return;
  const idString = id.toString();
  getId(idString.concat("Button")).style.visibility = "visible";
  getId(idString.concat("MoneyCostDisp")).innerHTML = numFormat(moneyCost);
  getId(idString.concat("ScienceCostDisp")).innerHTML = numFormat(scienceCost);
});
```

Comment: Getting a parsing error: unexpected token, about the comma in `{key, obj}`; would you know anything about that?

Comment: Sorry, mistyped. Use `Object.entries(UPGRADES)` instead, since `UPGRADES` is where all the objects are

Answer (score 0):

I see the problem here:
You create an array called `upgArray`, but then try to access `UPGRADES.upgArray` which is undefined. What you want to write there is likely `UPGRADES[upgArray[a]]`.

```
function checkVisiblityOnUpgrades () {

var upgArray = Object.keys(UPGRADES);
for (var a = 0; a < numUpgrades; a++) {

    if (UPGRADES[upgArray[a]].requiredScience <= resources.science) {
        var idString = UPGRADES[upgArray[a]].id.toString();
        getId(idString.concat("Button")).style.visibility = "visible";
        getId(idString.concat("MoneyCostDisp")).innerHTML = 
       numFormat(UPGRADES[upgArray[a]].moneyCost);
        getId(idString.concat("ScienceCostDisp")).innerHTML = 
        numFormat(UPGRADES[upgArray[a]].scienceCost);
        }
    }
}
```